# jQuery user editable table cell

Tags: jquery

I have looked into several editable table plugins but I am not sure they is really necessary for my needs. All I want to do is catch a click on a td element, grab the current value, then change the td html to an input + button and when the button is pressed, remove the input and button and place the new text in the td. Here is what I have and it isn't working at all. when you click on a td, the whole table disappears and is replaced with an input.

Here is the JS:

```
    var selectedObj;

  $('td').click(function(e){
      // Handle the click

     if ($('#currentInput').length == 0)
     {
          selectedObj = $(this);
        var currentValue = $(this).text();
        var newValue = currentValue;

        $(this).html("<input id='currentInput' type='text' value='"+currentValue+"'/> <button onclick='setNewValue()'>Set</button>");
     }

  });
  function setNewValue()
  {
            var newValue = $('#currentInput').val();

        selectedObj.html('');
            selectedObj.text(newValue);
  }
```

And the HTML:

```
<p> 
<table id='transitTable' border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" class='display' width="400">
<tr id='1'>
<td class="etsHeader etsLeft">H1</td>
<td class="etsHeader etsLeft">H2</td>
<td class="etsHeader etsLeft">H3</td>
<td class="etsHeader etsLeft">H4</td></tr>
<tr id='2'>
<td class="etsValue etsOdd etsLeft">R1</td>
<td class="etsValue etsOdd etsLeft">R1</td>
<td class="etsValue etsOdd etsLeft">R1</td>
<td class="etsValue etsOdd etsLeft">R1</td></tr>
<tr id='3'>
<td class="etsValue etsEven etsLeft">R2</td>
<td class="etsValue etsEven etsLeft">R2</td>
<td class="etsValue etsEven etsLeft">R2</td>
<td class="etsValue etsEven etsLeft">R2</td></tr></table></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are replacing the `td` with an `input` tag which is invalid in that context.

**offending code**

`$(this).html("<input id='currentInput' type='text' value='"+currentValue+"'/> <button onclick='setNewValue()'>Set</button>");`

Try to `.append()` to a `td` or wrap the `td` values in another tag.

Comment: When the input box shows us it is populated with all the text from all td tags. Any idea what is going on there?

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you try contentEditable = true,

Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/358ES/)

Comment: +1 since it's a viable solution, and since I didn't know about that before reading your answer.  Pretty cool, but won't work with some older browsers.

Comment: This is a great idea but wont work for my needs since I need it to work in internet explorer 8.